# Color of TextView shows as white on a real device with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have been trying my hands on `ConstraintLayout` and so far I have liked it *a lot* except now I have run into a peculiar problem. The same layout, if I design using a `RelativeLayout` displays the color of the contained `TextView`s as the default text color(greyish) but with `ConstraintLayout`, it shows white.

This happens on both a real device as well as an emulator with Android 5.0 but not on emulator(7.0). Does anyone know, why might this be happening?

Also, the obvious solution seems to be manually styling the color of the `TextView` in the layout to what it should be but that seems like a hack than a solution. I would be interested in knowing, why this is happening in the first place and if this hack is the only *solution*? (*I prefer not fixing it by forcing a color on `TextView` as the behavior is correct on Android 7.0*)

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that the Layout Editor shows them both as black/greyish so that is also a cue that the actual color should not be white.

---

For your reference, here are the 2 layouts that are more or less same(*there is a `Button` in one of them and `TextView` instead of `Button` in the other*) in which one is faulty.

**The layout that shows it white(issue in focus):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tutor_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_skill_set"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/skill_set"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_types"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/tutor_types" />

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

        <com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tutor_rating"
            android:layout_below="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            app:srb_starSize="13dp"
            app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
            app:srb_borderColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:srb_fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srb_starBorderWidth="1"
            app:srb_isIndicator="true"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6796875" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tutor_requested_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:text="Requested time"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/constraintLayout" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**The layout that shows it black/greyish(default as it should be)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:elevation="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tutor_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_skill_set"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/skill_set"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_types"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/tutor_types" />

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

        <com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tutor_rating"
            android:layout_below="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            app:srb_starSize="13dp"
            app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
            app:srb_borderColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:srb_fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srb_starBorderWidth="1"
            app:srb_isIndicator="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/request_tutor"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
            android:minHeight="25dp"
            android:minWidth="80dp"
            android:text="Request"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

---

*(**Note:** Although I tried using a Barrier below, it is in ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 beta and I would strictly refrain from using a beta version for production in this case)*

**EDIT 2:** Following @rami-jemli 's advice, here is the `ConstraintLayout` with a barrier with the problem still persisting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tutor_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_skill_set"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/skill_set"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_types"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/tutor_types" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

    <com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tutor_rating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:srb_starSize="13dp"
        app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
        app:srb_borderColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:srb_fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srb_starBorderWidth="1"
        app:srb_isIndicator="true"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6796875"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="250dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tutor_requested_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Requested time"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="tutor_rating,linearLayout"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="126dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output:(Dummy data)**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot believe this! I found the answer.

From the question, it is not possible to pinpoint what could be wrong because problem is not with the *layout*, `RecyclerView`, `AppCompat` or `ConstraintLayout`. The problem is with something called the *Themed Context*. I have been passing around application context in almost all cases but it turns out where the layout is concerned, it is recommended to pass in `Activity` instance itself(*which is a Themed context because it extends `ContextThemeWrapper` --more on this a bit later*).

So, for example, when we are instantiating a `LayoutManager` for a `RecyclerView`, we would pass in `Activity` instance. When we are inflating a layout item for a `RecyclerView`, we would again use the `Activity`.

Talking in this context, [`ContextThemeWrapper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) takes conceptual precedence as stated [here](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/which-context-should-i-use-in-android-e3133d00772c) and `Activity` subclasses it.

Also mentioned is,

> ### `ContextThemeWrapper` will apply your application theme
>
> The snippet of code I've shared above does not make this immediately
>   clear, however, you can write your own tests to verify this. The best
>   way I can think of doing this is to create a simple app with a
>   `ListView` that uses `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to display
>   items. Make your apps theme Light by default and then initialize your
>   `ArrayAdapter` using `getApplicationContext()`. You’ll notice that the
>   text is either not visible or barely visible because it will be white
>   by default whereas your theme should call for default text to be
>   black. Change the code, so that your code initializes the array
>   adapter with “this” (i.e the `Activity`) or simply `getContext()` and
>   you’ll see the text turns black.

And,

> **Do not use** `getApplicationContext()` with `LayoutInflater`, unless you really do want to ignore your theme.

---

*Hats off to @sockeqwe for his [answer on `SwitchCompat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563986/switchcompat-not-displaying-the-switch?noredirect=1&lq=1) that gave me this idea.*

**Note:** Previously, I had mentioned that this might be a bug in `ConstraintLayout`. I take that back and apologies to the folks working on `ConstraintLayout`(*which I have found totally awesome!*)

Lastly, thanks to all the folks who gave their precious time reading my question and churning their brainpower for answer.

Comment: Glad you were able to find your problem.  Can you accept your answer to make it obvious to those who find this in the future?

Comment: @Gary99 : Sure thing. Done.

Answer (score 3):

The way you are using `ConstraintLayout` now is wrong. You are not getting its performance benefits. There is no need for all the other ViewGroups (RelativeLayout, etc.) and the nested layouts. 
 
In your case, you need to use only one `ConstraintLayout` as a parent layout with no nested level. 
Use `Chains` instead of `LinearLayout`. 
Try to achieve this and update your question with the new code.

 Let's see what you get.

Comment: Well, that's what I had planned originally but while doing so, I encountered a problem with ConstraintLayout. You see, there is only 1 vertical constraint per view edge( for top and bottoms edges) I can have but I wanted my view to lie below the bottom edges of 2 other views. This is something I couldn't do with a flat ConstraintLayout. To give you an idea, see:  http://imgur.com/a/sw5bx . The *requested time* TextView has to be aligned below the LinearLayout's bottom as well as the rating bar on the right. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: To keep a view below the edge of two other views, you can use Barriers. They are part of the 1.1.0-beta1 release of  ConstraintLayout. You can still get a flat layout. Give it a try.

Comment: I kind of explained Barriers here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487758/align-constraintlayout-item-to-be-at-the-end-of-two-items/44489567#44489567)

Comment: Yeah...I saw a walkthrough for Barriers after you mentioned. Turns out, a simple Constraint Layout update to 1.1.0 beta won't visually facilitate the use of Barriers so I am now downloading AS 3.0 Canary-5 Preview to use it. But a big thanks for pointing me in this direction. +1

Comment: I was able to put a barrier in place successfully but the white color bug still remains...;(

Comment: Great. Please update your question with the new layout code and point out which view exactly is showing the color problem

Comment: I have put the new info. within EDIT 2. The problem as you can see persists in all the TextViews(Note that above layout is for each item that has been displayed in the list). Side note: Android Studio 3.0 sucks! Couldn't find anywhere the Screen Capture functionality. Also, it is unable to connect to active process on the device unless opened in debug mode - such a turn off really...

Comment: Although helpful this does not provide answer to the question.